# Problem on homomorphisms and fibres

Tags: group-theory

I have a function $f: R^2$ to $R$ defined by $f(x,y) = y-x$. Let $H= [(x,x)|x ∈ R]$ and $H$ is a subset of $R^2$. Thinking of $R^2$ and $R$ as groups under vector addition:

I need to check that $f$ is a homomorphism, and $H = ker f$.

I want to see if my understanding is correct, that in order to check that $f$ is a homomorphism, then $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$? But how do I manipulate a function of two variables?

Also, I know that the cosets of $H$ are the fibers of $f$. How do I show directly that the coset $H + (12,1)$ is a fibre of $f$?

Lastly, let $c$ be in R. Give one example of some $(a,b)$ in $R^2$ such that the coset $H +(a,b)$ is equal to the fibre of $f$ at $c$.

Group theory is complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check $f((x_1, y_1) + (x_2, y_2)) = f(x_1, y_1) + f(x_2, y_2)$.

To show $H + (12, 1)$ is a fibre of $f$, note that $(12, 1) \in H + (12, 1)$ and $f(12, 1) = 1 -12 = -11$. So if it is a fibre of $f$, it must be $f^{-1}(-11)$. All you need to do is show that $H + (12, 1) = f^{-1}(-11)$, i.e. $(x, y) \in H + (12, 1) \Leftrightarrow f(x, y) = -11$.

Repeat the previous paragraph for your chosen value of $c$.